# Preventing apt-get from downloading other packages

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I've recently installed Oracle JDK on my Ubuntu. Now when I download any package, apt-get first tries to download oracle-java8-installer. How can I stop it from doing that?

Edit: Here's the output of `apt-cache policy oracle-java8-installer`:

```
oracle-java8-installer:
  Installed: 8b108-0~webupd8~0
  Candidate: 8b108-0~webupd8~0
  Version table:
 *** 8b108-0~webupd8~0 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Technically, questions about 13.10 are off-topic as it's not been released yet. Also, this is very likely a duplicate question. But it would help to know how you installed the Oracle JDK exactly, given that it's not included in Ubuntu directly.

Comment: This is unlikely to have anything to do with 13.10; I merely used the tag to say what version I was on.

Comment: @dobey I downloaded the tar package from Oracle, untarred it, moved the folder to /usr/lib/jvm, and set it as default using update-alternatives.

Comment: Please include the output of `apt-cache policy oracle-java-installer` in your question.

Comment: @dobey Did as you said. The correct package name is oracle-java8-installer by the way.

Comment: Can you add the output where apt-get tries to download the java installer again? Also the output of `sudo apt-get check`.